# How to register existing gitlab runner in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab runner in kubernetes - using the gitlab-runner Helm chart from https://charts.gitlab.io. Whenever the pod drops, or shifts to another node the runner re-registers, loses its tags and locked state - so needs to be reconfigured.

Have tried setting `runnerToken`, but the logs show an error:

```
ERROR: Verifying runner... is removed               runner=xxxxxx
PANIC: Failed to verify the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

How do I get it to re-register with the same tags and state?